# Slide up footer once user scrolls to bottom of page - flickering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
var footer = $('.footer'),
    extra = 0;

// footer.css({ opacity: '0', display: 'block' });


$(window).scroll(function() {

   var scrolledLength = ( $(window).height() + extra ) + $(window).scrollTop(),
       documentHeight = $(document).height();



    console.log( 'Scroll length: ' + scrolledLength + ' Document height: ' + documentHeight )


   if( scrolledLength >= documentHeight ) {

       footer
          .addClass('bottom')
          // .slideUp();
          .stop().animate({ bottom: '0', opacity: '1' }, 300);

   }
   else if ( scrolledLength <= documentHeight && footer.hasClass('bottom') ) {
        footer
           .removeClass('bottom')
          //  .slideDown();
           .stop().animate({ bottom: '-100', opacity: '0' }, 300);

   }
});
```

My goal is to show the footer once the user scrolls to the bottom of the page. If the user scrolls up again, I want the footer to slide down again.

Right now I am checking the `scrolledLength` against the `documentHeight`. However, the problem seems to be that the `documentHeight` changes once we reach the bottom, since the footer appears and the extends the document.

My code does work, the footer does not disappear again or anything, but it is flickering a lot (and then eventually calms down), as it is being calculated anew. How could i solve this? Are there any mistakes in my code?

Comment: store a boolean if footer is visible, and if it is, calculate height as documenth height - footerHeight?

Answer (score 1):

You are already adding a class to the footer, the animation can be handled using CSS:

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: -100px;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

.footer.bottom {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

**Update:** [JSFiddle with working slide up footer](https://jsfiddle.net/u75d9pvc/2/).

Obviously I'm guessing at how the footer should by styled since you haven't provided the CSS - this code will simply animate the footer up when the class `.bottom` is added.

Comment: thanks. it does not pop up however, it seems to just stay at the bottom and move further down, but not just appear out of 'nowhere' as it were. Moving back up it looks good though, disappearing sliding down!

Comment: If you can post a link to you code on JSFiddle or Codepen I can make the relevant changes.

Comment: thank you so much. i somehow can't get it to work in this jsfiddle, but this is my code so far: https://jsfiddle.net/u75d9pvc/1/ I will have another look and try to get it working like it is on my machine, but have never used jsfiddle before, not sure what is going on

Comment: I've updated the post with a link to a working fiddle. I strongly recommend you use `.footer` only for the slide up animation, then place your Bootstrap columns and any flexbox code inside that - this will make troubleshooting and working with the code easier.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use css transition instead:

```js
var footer = $('.footer'),
    extra = 0;

// footer.css({ opacity: '0', display: 'block' });


$(window).scroll(function() {

   var scrolledLength = ( $(window).height() + extra ) + $(window).scrollTop(),
       documentHeight = $(document).height();


   if( scrolledLength >= documentHeight ) {

       footer
          .addClass('open')
          
         

   }
   else if ( scrolledLength <= documentHeight && footer.hasClass('open') ) {
        footer
           .removeClass('open')
          

   }
});
```

```css
.container{
  position:relative;
  height: 200vh;
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.footer{
  height: 100px;
  width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  bottom:-100px;
  background-color: black;
  transition: 1s;
  
}

.open{
  bottom:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

    <div class="footer"></div>
    
</div>
```